# Using GET method to work for POST, PUT or DELETE

Tags: java, rest

I am consuming a REST webservice, which is hosted on a remote server.
Now, the web service's POST, PUT and DELETE methods are blocked by the server's firewall. So I have only GET method left.
Is there a way I can use GET to work as POST or PUT or DELETE ?
I am using jersey api for consuming the services.

Comment: I guess you can't, as the GET method is not allowed to have a request body -> you are not able to send a payload to the server.

Comment: If the webservice provides functionality for POST/PUT/DELETE, but they're blocked, it's not really the programmer's job to work around it. Why would they block the methods if they're supposed to be used? Ask the server administrators what kind of tomfoolery they're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/messages/9962

> Yes. In other words, any HTTP request message is allowed to contain
>   a message body, and thus must parse messages with that in mind.
>   Server semantics for GET, however, are restricted such that a body,
>   if any, has no semantic meaning to the request. The requirements
>   on parsing are separate from the requirements on method semantics.
>
> So, yes, you can send a body with GET, and no, it is never useful
>   to do so.
>
> This is part of the layered design of HTTP/1.1 that will become
>   clear again once the spec is partitioned (work in progress).
>   ....Roy

This means you can send a message body with your GET request but it would have no meaning. If your server firewall doesn't allow you to receive requests other than GET you should try to talk to your admin, change the server and if that's not possible due to company reasons you should escalate it via your manager.

edit: as Kayaman said it's not your job to do that. if you are not given the right infrastructure, you just can't work. if you are not given a computer nobody would expect you to be able to code.